# Laymans explanation of this Energy Transformation equation...

Tags: physics, nonlinear-system

I know this will be basic but I'm trying to visualise this pendulum equation and it's left me a little stumped.

If we have a mass on the end of a string and the mass is allowed to swing like a pendulum.  Here we have $ t $ = time and $ x $ = inclination from the vertical.  So we have the following equation of motion:

$$ \ddot x + \omega^2\sin x = 0 $$

It is possible to re-write $ \ddot x $ in terms of $ \dot x $ and $ x $ by using:

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\ddot x & = \frac{d \dot x}{dt} \\
& = \frac{d \dot x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} \\
& =  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot x^2\right)
\end{align}$$

Ok, I get the $$ \ddot x = \frac{d \dot x}{dt} $$

part.  Whats getting me is $$ \frac{d \dot x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} $$

Ok, so we have the inclination changing with respect to time which is the $$ \frac{dx}{dt} $$

For the $$ \frac{d \dot x}{dx} $$

term, are we saying that it's the velocity changing with respect to the inclination?  I'm struggling to somehow visualise that in my head.  Any pointers?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Yes, $d\dot x/dx$ represents the instantaneous rate of change of velocity $\dot x$ with respect to inclination $x$.  If $d\dot x/dx > 0$ then velocity increases as inclination increases.  If $d\dot x/dx < 0$ then velocity decreases as inclination increases.

Answer (score 1):

By writing
$$\frac{d\dot x}{dt}=\frac{d\dot x}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt},$$
you have assumed that $\dot x$ can be written as a function of $x$, so that you can apply chain rule. However, in the case of the pendulum, we cannot write $\dot x$ as a function of $x$.

It is easy to see that the pendulum can be either rising or dropping if we are only given the position of the pendulum, so $\dot x$ is not a function of $x$, and writing $$\frac{d\dot x}{dx}$$ makes no sense.